# Stop watch android - pause, then start and begin from where it left off

Tags: java, android, android-activity, runnable

I have two buttons "Start" and "Pause"and one Textview.

The problem I have is when I press the Pause button and then press start button after, the stopwatch doesn't begin from where it left off.

Thanks for the help

```
public class StopWatch extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextView timeflg;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private long mStartTime = 0L;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    long millis = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (mStartTime == 0L) {
            mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);


            }

            timeflg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeflag);

            startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
            startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view){

                    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);

                }
            });

            pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
            pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view){

                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

                }
            });

    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                    millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;

                    int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
                    int minutes = seconds / 60;
                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                    int milliseconds = (int) (millis%1000);
                    timeflg.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds)+ ":" 
                    + String.format("%03d",milliseconds));
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
            }

    };



}
```

Comment: For future reference, you need to select all your code and then click the "{ }" button to ensure *all* your code is displayed in the code block.

Comment: And your example isn't very clear at all... can you clarify.

Comment: Thanks, so normally when you press the stop button the timer would stop, and then when you press the start button it starts the timer again. Time is not reset to zero, it should begin from where it left off. I am not sure where is goes wrong with my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the problem:

`millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;`

`mStartTime` is initialized when activity is created.
Then presented time is calculated since mStartTime.

EDIT:
I see you still don't get it.

Initialize mStartTime when pressing start Button, it's current lapse start time:

```
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
            }
        });
```

Calculate mCurrenLapse time. 
Display time is time of past lapses and time of current lapse:

```
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                mCurrentLapse = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;
                //
                long displayTime = mTime + mCurrentLapse;
                .
                .
                .
```

Total time is time of all lapses, when pause is clicked then current time lapse is added to total time:

```
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                mTime += mCurrentLapse;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out that even when I call removeCallbacks(), the thread still running? why?

Comment: removeCallbacks() is connected with Handlers and has nothing to Threads.

Comment: Here is the problem, I don't want to get the total time, I want to stop the time, and start again from that time. Is there a way I can save the timer once you press the pause button?

Comment: I meant total time as sum of running time. When you stop it stops counting too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it finally. I love you.